# Java backup mysqldump.exe absolute path to relative path

Tags: java, relative-path, absolute-path

How can I convert this absolute file path to relative path, so whenever I install the system to any desktop and use backup there would be no problem.

This is the absolute path of mysqldump.exe

```
String executeCmd = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u " + dbUsername + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + backupDatabaseTextField.getText();
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

Comment: This depends on where your "mysqldump.exe" file is installed relative to the directory which will be your working dir. Where have you installed "mysqldump.exe"? And from where are you starting your java application?

Comment: This is where I install my "mysqldum.exe" "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump".
For my java application, I have already installed it to my client's 3 computers but one computer is not working because the system won't find the absolute path on the computer, I have been using xampp for production which is obviously wrong, I decided to use mysql server, which is why I'm also changing path directory. to relative path

Comment: When "mysqldump.exe" is installed in "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/", in which directory is your java application installed?

Comment: My java application is installed in the program files

Comment: I already solved it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so by accident, I just solved my problem. Turns out just i just need to remove 
the "C:" from

```
String executeCmd = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u " + dbUsername + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + backupDatabaseTextField.getText();
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

and the result should be like this and it works.

```
String executeCmd = "/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u " + dbUsername + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + backupDatabaseTextField.getText();
```